# How to change vertical alignment of content with a button element?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, flexbox

I'm working on a project where there is a row of controls, each of which is a button element. There is content inside of the buttons, and they are laid out in a row with flexbox. The button element centers its content vertically, and I can't figure out how to override it to vertically align it at the top of the button. The controls all need to be the same height and same width, and clicking anywhere in the borders must count as a click on the button.

This Codepen shows the problem clearly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPpqdz

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 80%;
}

button,
.object {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>What it looks like</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>I am Content</button>
  <button>I am Much Longer Content That Goes Here and Here</button>
  <button>I am Content</button>
</div>

<h1>What I want it to look like</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="object">I am Content</div>
  <div class="object">I am Much Longer Content That Goes Here and Here</div>
  <div class="object">I am Content</div>
</div>
```

I realize this issue could be solved by not using button elements, but I also feel like I SHOULD be able to override this behavior of button elements. I'd like to figure this out for my own sanity!

Comment: not sure what you want, but it seem like a job for javascript, here is something to try (jQuery) `$(button).click(function() {$('el').css({"new-style":"value"})})`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, having `h2` and `p` inside `button` is not valid HTML.

Secondly, there is no simple way to control the position of elements in a button, especially vertically.

But if you really really must use this **BROKEN** HTML, and only the top alignment is important, you can force the elements to take up fixed heights so that the button will align them at the top, like so:

```
button > h2 {
    height: 48px;
}

button > p {
    height: 16px;
}
```

I must say this is still not exactly the same as using `<div>`, so I don't know if this is sufficient.

In any case, do seriously try to convince those in charge of the "larger context of the project" to use proper valid HTML.

**Edit:**

If only inline elements are used inside the button, the problem becomes more manageable. The only caveat is: you need to know beforehand the height of the button. You can then simulate top-bottom flow using paddings.

```
button {
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 5em; /* make sure bottom + top padding == height */
    padding-left: 1em;
    height: 6em;
}
```

Still probably not ideal - feels like a heavily plastered hack solution.

Comment: This issue is exactly the same if I use spans or other inline elements inside of the button, which is valid. I've updated the codepen and I'll update the question as well. It's important that the solution doesn't impose static heights for any of the content within the button.

Answer (score 0):

### *I'm not sure what do you want and what do you mean by "how to override it to vertically align it at the top of the button?"? but I hope this code is what you want.(same height, width and even with spaces also buttons matching with div (.objects).

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  width: 90%;
}

button, .object {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0em 0.3em 0em 0em;
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. The buttons all need to be the same width, and even if they didn't, you'll notice the issue is still present at certain browser widths.

Comment: can you please draw with explanation of how do you want it to be.
because I'm not able to know I did close or totally I'm far from what do you want.